# GulpJS - how to read value from xml file and add it to a json file?

Tags: javascript, json, xml, node.js, gulp

I'm a bit of a noob to Gulp/Node programming and I'm struggling to do a simple task :)

I have an XML file which contains a node like this: `<widget version="1.1"></widget>`

I would like to read out the version value and put that value into a json file.  How is this achieved?

Here's what I tried:

```
var configXml      = 'config.xml';
var enTemplateJson = 'signing/en_template.json';
```

**CODE**:

**SCRIPT**:

```
return gulp.src([configXml])
          .pipe(cheerio({
            parserOptions: {
              xmlMode: true
            },
            run: function($, file) {
              $('widget').each(function() {
                var version = $(this)[0].attribs.version;

                // prints version 1.1
                console.log(version);
              })
            }
          }))
          .pipe(gulp.dest('test.xml'));
```

Comment: what is the exact problem you are getting

Comment: I need to read the version value from the XML file and write it to the JSON file.  I'm not able to achieve this in gulp unless there's a way to open two files at the same time?

Comment: is the `en_template.json` file an existing json file that you need to patch with the version from `config.xml`? Or can you recreate it each time?

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out:

```
// App Versioning
gulp.task('update-version', function() {
  // Read config.xml file synchronously
  var xml       = fs.readFileSync('./config.xml');

  // Use cheerio to parse the xml and extract the version number
  var $         = cheerio.load(xml, { xmlMode: true });
  var version   = $('widget')[0].attribs.version;

  return gulp.src('signing/en.json')
          .pipe(replace(/\${APP_VERSION}/, version))
          .pipe(gulp.dest('app/i18n'));
});
```